# Kubenetes ApiService regenerated after deletion

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, cert-manager

I'm attempting to upgrade cert-manager in my kubernetes cluster. Currently the version installed was pre crd name change and I'm trying to clean up the old CRDs.

```
> kubectl get crd | grep certmanager.k8s.io 

certificates.certmanager.k8s.io                2020-01-31T08:25:56Z
challenges.certmanager.k8s.io                  2020-01-31T08:25:56Z
clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io              2020-01-31T08:25:58Z
issuers.certmanager.k8s.io                     2020-01-31T08:25:03Z
orders.certmanager.k8s.io                      2020-01-31T08:25:08Z
```

After identifying the crds I delete them:

```
> kubectl delete customresourcedefinition certificates.certmanager.k8s.io challenges.certmanager.k8s.io clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io issuers.certmanager.k8s.io orders.certmanager.k8s.io

customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "certificates.certmanager.k8s.io" deleted
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "challenges.certmanager.k8s.io" deleted
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io" deleted
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "issuers.certmanager.k8s.io" deleted
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "orders.certmanager.k8s.io" deleted
```

Following deletion `kubectl get crd | grep certmanager.k8s.io` shows no crds but after about 30 seconds they are regenerated. Where do I need to look to identify what's causing them to regenerate.

All other cert-manager resources have been deleted.

This has come about because I don't seem to be able to view/edit/delete resources in the new CRD but applying changes updates the (hidden) resource.

Comment: Do a get pods —all-namespaces to check if you missed something.

Comment: Yep nothing there. The cert-manager was in it's own namespace which is also gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is probably caused by the Istio addon. When Istio is enabled in the cluster, the following resources are created:

certificates.certmanager.k8s.io,

challenges.certmanager.k8s.io,

clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io,

issuers.certmanager.k8s.io, and

orders.certmanager.k8s.io

.. and istio is in charge of reconciling them periodically. This means if you delete them manually they will get automatically recreated.

You can verify this by creating a sample cluster with enabling istio and then run the following command:

~$ kubectl get apiservices

~$ kubectl get customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io, and

~$ kubectl describe customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io certificates.certmanager.k8s.io

There is an addon with label “addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile” which by definition periodically reconciles and this is the reason why the CRD (managed by Istio) kept getting recreated. For details you can refer to this [URL](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager). Please try disabling the addon before doing the deletion."